# iOs and android time in milliseconds are not getting same?

Tags: android, datetime, swift4

I Have a project in iOS and Android, in which I am using firebase as my remote server. I have to save the current date in the firebase from android and iOS as well. So that I can fetch it later and find difference between some dates. In iOS I am saving the time as time in milliseconds since 1970. In android i am simply taking it as `system.getTimeInMillis();`

But later I found that both are not returning the same value. I want to make it same for android and iOS. I have tried some methods from stack overflow and other forums. But I couldn't find an answer. Sometimes iOS saving value as double and android saving it long. 
I have tried

```
Calendar mycalendar  = Calendar.getInstance();
mycalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
mycalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
mycalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long times = mycalendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

still it is not returning same value in iOS for the same time. So anyone can tell how to get time in milliseconds same for android and iOS?

Comment: in IOS are you using Objective C or Swift?

Comment: A quick idea is to use the server time rather than the device time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NTP based TrueTime library.
For the same use case, we were all most able to achieve exact time in both the platforms. Keep NTP server same for both the platforms.

Android: https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android

iOS: https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift

Comment: In ios timeInMilliseconds return double value and in android the value was Long. How do we match android &ios timeInSeconds value?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect two different devices to be in sync to the millisecond without a LOT of work to make it so?  Its basically impossible.  Time isn't a universal constant that magically gets zapped into your phone-  there's clocks and hardware inside the devices that will always be subtly off, and even if synced to a network, and the network is syncing both devices there's network lag to deal with.

I highly suggest you read https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time and https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time  You can't think about time the way you are.

Comment: I am accessing the same server from android and iOS. So that i have to fetch time saved by both the devices and have to calculate the number of days passed from that date. But when i take time saved by ios device in android phone its giving wrong values after calculating the difference.